# Solving N-Queen problem using random picked queens

Tags: c++, n-queens

My idea is to store the position of the queens in an 1D array with queen[i]=row and i = column, which is randomly generated in a way that no queen is on the same row or column. This will only leave threatened queens on diagonal lines

I scan the lines for threatened queens and store them on another array. The queens in this array will then be selected randomly to swap with another randomly selected queen on the board(swap the row index).

**Update**

I changed few things and it got better but still can't reach 1000 queens

Each time it successfully perform a swap that can reduce conflict, loop count +1. And after n*90 counts (I noticed that if the board is solved, for example 100 queens, it would take around 8000-10000 loop and so on. So I came up with this), the program will generate another board and start again

The problem is, it can't run efficiently pass 500 queens and each loop takes much longer as the number of queen goes up

Anyone knows how can I improve my code to reach 1000 queens and more ?

Here's my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;

int queen[1000];
int threat[1000];
int conflict;
long int loop;
int a;


void Out(int arr1[]){
    for(int i =1;i<=a;i++)
        cout << arr1[i] << "\t";
}
// check for conflict on diagonal lines
int Search(int arr1[]){
    conflict =0;
    for(int i=1;i<=a;i++){
        for(int j=i+1;j<=a;j++) {
            if (arr1[i] + i == arr1[j] + j || arr1[i]-i == arr1[j]-j) {
                threat[i] = i; // register position of threatened queen
                threat[j] = j;
                conflict++;
            }
        }
    }
    return conflict;
}
// generate a board with no queen on the same row or column
void Init(){
    for(int i=1;i<=a;i++){
        queen[i]=i;
    }
    shuffle(queen+1,queen+a, std::mt19937(std::random_device()()));
    while(Search(queen)>=a*0.8)
        Init();
}

// check if it's ok to swap
bool isOK(int arr1[],int arr2[]){
    if(Search(arr1)>=Search(arr2))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
// move the queen to reduce conflict
void MoveQueen(int arr1[]){
    loop=0;

    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 mt(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(1, a);
    int temp[1000];
    int g[10];
    for(int i=1;i<=a;i++) {
        temp[i] = arr1[i]; // create a temporary array to store current position of the queens
    }
    while(Search(arr1)!=0){
        int k = dist(mt); // pick a random threatened queen
        if(threat[k]!=0) {
            int j = dist(mt);
            swap(temp[j], temp[threat[k]]); //swap it with a random queen on the board
            if (isOK(temp,arr1)) { // check if the swap reduces conflict
                for (int i = 1; i <= a; i++) {//revert the position if not
                    temp[i] = arr1[i];
                }
            } else {
                for (int i = 1; i <= a; i++) {//update if it does
                    arr1[i] = temp[i];
                }
            }
        }
        loop ++;
        // if the loop count passes a certain amount, try again
        if(loop>a*90){
            for(int i =1;i<=a;i++){
                queen[i]=0;
                temp[i]=0;
            }
            Init();
            Out(queen); // print out new board
            cout << endl;
            MoveQueen(queen);
        }
    }
}
int main(){
    cin >> a;
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    Init();
    Out(queen);
    cout << endl;
    MoveQueen(queen);
    Out(queen);
    cout << endl << loop << endl;
    auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(stop-start);
    cout << duration.count();
}
```

Comment: too many nested loops. That can have a huge impact on performance.

Comment: @Waqar
I tried moving the loops around and I discover one more thing

It's still stuck at the first generation but when it does not (i don't write down all the outcomes and measure but it feels like 50% of the time), it solves 100 queen in under 1 second and with 2-3 more generation